# Unable to open broken data set in MapInfo 17.0

Tags: mapinfo

When I try to open an workspace/map in MapInfo 17.0 that has a broken dataset or it can't find the direction to an dataset, my MapInfo freezes.

Is there a way I can skip past the broken dataset and still open the workspace/map without MapInfo freezing?

Comment: backup your .wor file and you can open in an editor (like notepad++) and your see Open Table "c:\yourfolder\yourdata" As yourdata you can remove that and 'interactive' once save open in Mapinfo and save.

Answer (score 0):

If the dataset exists on disk, MapInfo Pro will try to open it.

You can try to move the broken dataset to a subfolder so that MapInfo Pro can't find it. This will make MapInfo Pro prompt you to select the dataset it can't locate.

This option gives you the ability to select a different dataset or to skip that dataset completely and continue loading the workspace without the missing dataset.